# TextView not appearing on cardView

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am not sure how the layout really works or how to debug .This is how the CardView xml file looks like. I know the text is there. But it being covered by the image

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_image"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in the app.

[image]

Without the ImageView it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use fill_parent this is deprecated and use layout weight to show also your text. Here are some more informations about the correct use of layout_weight [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/info_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it and looks great now.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This attribute causes a view to fill the entire parent view. (Note that it this is the same as `fill_parent`. You should use `match_parent`, which was introduced in API 8.) This causes the `ImageView` to fill the entire `CardView` and does not allow the `TextView` to take any space.

You should set `android:layout_height="0dp"` for both children and use `andorid:layout_weight` to specify how much space each should take.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Linear Layout you can use Relative Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info_image" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/info_image"
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```